# Appcelerator Android app starts crashing when Internet is turned Off

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I am working with Titanium Appcelerator 1.8.1 Android SDK. App is working perfect when Internet connectivity is on. But when I turn the connectivity is off, App crashes in the start. Nothing works as expected. I am supposed to develop offline feature, which enables app to be working as expected when it's offline and syncs data when it is online.

I had used following permission set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: When I turn on Internet on Simulator app works. On Android follow following steps: 1) Open Settings. 2) Go to Wireless Networks and Data. 3) Turn on "Data Enabled" to turn Internet on else Internet will be off.

Comment: You write 'crash' and yet do not refer to logcat output concerning the crash.  Please correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Branch your logic like

```
if(Ti.Network.online){
   //sync data
}else{
   /fetch data from local persisitance
}
```

And FYI i guess Titanium takes care of adding these permissions to the manifest file by default.

Comment: This does not help. Because when I try to turn off Internet, app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

That may be caused by the "Live view" option activated, it need the mobile to be in the same network as the PC where Appcelerator is running. If you are developing an offline app, you have to unselect that option, that way you can run your app without beeing in the same network as the PC.
[Image of Live View option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1yEs.png)